# D3 Line chart doesn't return correct value on ticks mouse over

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, data-visualization, linechart

I have a line chart with current year and comparison year / previous period. I would like to show a tooltip on hover, so it will display the current tick's value for both current's years and the comparing year. However, I've noticed that the total value returned doesn't match the amount on the y-axis (please see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot]

As per image above the value should be between 30M - 40M but its showing as 56150248.2.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-carson-ge5r0?file=/src/LineChart.js)

```
// tooltip on x axis
    d3.selectAll(".xAxis > .tick")
      .style("color", "#65757E")
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        console.log("data");
        const mousePosition = d3.pointer(d);
        const data = yScale.invert(mousePosition[0]);
        console.log("pos", mousePosition);
        console.log("data", data);
      })
      .on("mouseout", (d) => {
        console.log("test");
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is the following:

- your selection for the mouseover is `d3.selectAll(".xAxis > .tick")`
- on the line: `.on("mouseover", function (d) {`
  the argument `d` refers to the event beeing passed. I recommend
  calling it `event` instead of `d` otherwise it confusing
- The mousePosition is initialized by an array with weird coordinates, namely coordinates relative to the selection (which are the ticks)

See: [d3.pointer(event[, target])](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/README.md#pointer)

> Returns a two-element array of numbers [x, y] representing the
> coordinates of the specified event relative to the specified target.
> event can be a MouseEvent, a PointerEvent, a Touch, or a custom event
> holding a UIEvent as event.sourceEvent.
>
> If target is not specified, it defaults to the source event’s
> currentTarget property, if available. If the target is an SVG element,
> the event’s coordinates are transformed using the inverse of the
> screen coordinate transformation matrix. If the target is an HTML
> element, the event’s coordinates are translated relative to the
> top-left corner of the target’s bounding client rectangle. (As such,
> the coordinate system can only be translated relative to the client
> coordinates. See also GeometryUtils.) Otherwise, [event.pageX,
> event.pageY] is returned.

- With `const data = yScale.invert(mousePosition[0]);` you refer to the x position with mousePosition[0], you probably meant mousePosition[1]

To use coordinates which you invert with the yscale you want the coordinates to be relative to the translated g directly under the svg. You have the selection of that element already referenced by the variable svg.

```
// tooltip on the g child of the svg
    svg  
      .style("color", "#65757E")
      .on("mouseover", function (event) {
        console.log("data");
        const mousePosition = d3.pointer(event);
        const data = yScale.invert(mousePosition[1]);
        console.log("pos", mousePosition);
        console.log("data", data);
      })
      .on("mouseout", (event) => {
        console.log("test");
      });
```

**Update 06/13/2021** based on the comments below:
You may want to do something like this (not sure if I reference the right data, but you can work from this:

```
d3.selectAll(".xAxis > .tick")  
      .style("color", "#65757E")
      .on("mousemove", function (event) {
        const mousePosition = d3.pointer(event, svg.node()); // gets [x,y]
        console.log("mouse position:", mousePosition);
        const currentDate = xScale.invert(mousePosition[0]); // converts x to date
        console.log("date at position:", currentDate);
        const bisect = d3.bisector(d => new Date(d.date)) // create a bisector

        const index_currentData = bisect.right(lineChartData.values[0].dataset, currentDate);     
        if (index_currentData < lineChartData.values[0].dataset.length) {
          console.log(`Current data at index[${index_currentData}]: ${lineChartData.values[0].dataset[index_currentData].value}`);
        }

        const index_comparisonData = bisect.right(comparisonData.values[0].dataset, currentDate);     
        if (index_comparisonData < comparisonData.values[0].dataset.length) {
          console.log(`Comparison data at index[${index_comparisonData}]: ${comparisonData.values[0].dataset[index_comparisonData].value}`);
        }
      })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By using `svg` in this case works, however tooltips appears every single when I hover over anywhere in the chart, but how to make this appear only when hovering on ticks?

Comment: Basically I have to pick the values at that exact point of time just on that particular tick, as I have a tooltip with two values with some colour codes labels, e.g red for current period and blue for comparing period, I'm figuring out how to grab values by hovering over the same one tick? So no matter where on the tick my mouse is, tooltip show two values for each line. And values are constant, not affected by mouse `y` position on that tick.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope you can work from this.... I am not sure why you are using 2 separate y scales...

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated indeed. I'm using one yScale for current period lines and yScale2 for comparing period, couldn't come up with more elegant solution ...

Comment: I was thinking you could use the same yscale for both lines... In my updated answer the data at one point seems similar, was is probably me not understand the data you have. But I hope the correct use of d3.pointer() and d3.bisector() becomes clear

Comment: also the x scale you might consider to use the same (by initializing it with min of both and max of both datasets

Comment: thank you, for some reason only current period works but on hover I don't see a `console.log` for comparison data https://imgur.com/a/nqb8Xt4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233721/discussion-between-ee2dev-and-alina-khachatrian).